# Here map SDK for android voice catalog speaking in miles or feet's instead of meters

Tags: java, here-api

Does here SDK for android and ios provide voice speaking in feet's or miles instead of meters?

For example while navigation is running and the speaker says "In 100 meters you will arrive at your destination" I want instead of meters to say "In 100 feet's you will arrive at your destination"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the Navigation manager's unit settings: https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/content/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/guidance/NavigationManager.UnitSystem.html#IMPERIAL

You need to do this:
navigationManager.setDistanceUnit(NavigationManager.IMPERIAL);

https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/content/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/guidance/NavigationManager.html#setDistanceUnit-com.here.android.mpa.guidance.NavigationManager.UnitSystem-

Comment: Thanks David, i got it working by changing manager to `navigationManager.setDistanceUnit(NavigationManager.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL_US);`

Comment: Could you please prompt how do this in iOS SDK?

Comment: @DimaPaliychuk ```self.navigationManager.voicePackageMeasurementSystem = .imperialUS```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late but just leaving solution here for anyone else.

for Android:

```
navigationManager.setDistanceUnit(NavigationManager.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL_US);
```

For IOS

```
self.navigationManager.voicePackageMeasurementSystem = .imperialUS
```